# Running Coldfusion Commands inside an HTML File?

Tags: apache-2.2, coldfusion

Is it possible to run CF commands inside an HTML file by updating Apache configs/htaccess file? When I searched online, I didn't come across any answers for CF, saw several posting for PHP (perhaps I am not searching for the right terms ... ?).

Specifically, we have CF 6 (I know, don't say it) on Solaris, and Apache 2, and was thinking of using this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-coldfusion .html
```

so we can use cfinclude inside the HTML files, but this did not work. Your time, ideas and thoughts are much appreciated!

KM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to add .html to the AddHandler directive in the configuration for your Apache server:

```
AddHandler jrun-handler .jsp .jws .cfm .cfml .cfc .cfr .cfswf .html
```

If you run multiple sites on this ColdFusion server, you should probably look to do this just for the site in question and not server-wide. You'd add a lot of load to the server if you have it parse all HTML files looking for CFML instructions.